# Value of Type 'UIImage' Has No Member

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift2

The error I am getting says:

> Value of Type 'UIImage' Has no Member 'thumbnailImage'

I have searched other questions and solutions but I don't understand how to implement them into my code. Please help me out in solving this problem.

```
let image = UIImage(data: newProfilePictureData)
let mediumImage: UIImage = image!.thumbnailImage(280, transparentBorder: 0, cornerRadius: 0, interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.High)
let smallRoundedImage: UIImage = image!.thumbnailImage(64, transparentBorder: 0, cornerRadius: 0, interpolationQuality: CGInterpolationQuality.Low)
```

Comment: @AshishKakkad can you rewrite the code to fix the error. Im very new to this and I still have no idea what to do.

Comment: Yeah i imported all of the necessary classes.

Comment: What do you mean? The import statements are on the top of the file if thats what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can generate thumb image from the original Image:

```
func generateThumbImage() -> UIImage{

        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: newProfilePictureData)
        let thumbSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbSize)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, thumbSize.width, thumbSize.height))
        let thumbImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return thumbImage
    }
```